# Call hydra.utils.instantiate inside configuration

Tags: python-3.x, fb-hydra

The following works:

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(early_stop_callback=hydra.utils.instantiate(cfg.callbacks.early_stopping),
                     **cfg.trainer)
```

But it makes `early_stopping` a required parameter. Is there a better way or a way to specify all this in the configuration with something similar to the following?

```
$ cat trainer.yaml
trainer:
  cls: pytorch_lightning.Trainer
  params:
    early_stop_callback: instantiate(cfg.callbacks.early_stopping)
```

So that I can do:

```
trainer = hydra.utils.instantiate(cfg.trainer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hydra 1.1.0 (2021-06-09) now supports recursive instantiation, see the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/main/NEWS.md), and in particular this [issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/566).

Answer (score 0):

Hydra does not currently support recursive instantiation.
This is planned for the next major version though, follow [this issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/566).